# Radio Station Playing Playlist in N minutes

Tags: combinatorics

In radio station's playlist there one song of 1 min , 5 song of 2 min each and 3 songs of 3 min each. The station plays full songs continuously for N minutes. 
How much Ways there are for play the songs?

Play Order Is important , and there isn't limit of times of play the same song.

What is the approach that i need to use then I try to solve the question?

Comment: Is $N \le 20$? Are repeats of a song allowed?

Comment: Play order is important , and there are no limit of num of times that song can be appeared. There is no condition for N.

Comment: You can set up a recursion, by considering the number of ways of having full songs up to time $N-1$ followed by a one minute song plus the number of ways of having full songs up to time $N-2$ followed by a two minute song plus the number of ways of having full songs up to time $N-3$ followed by a three minute song.  You could then see what values you actually get, produce a hypothesis for the number such as $\frac1{16}\left(3^{N+2} + (-1)^N(4N+7)\right)$ and then prove it is correct by induction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_k$ be number of ways to create playlist of length $k$. Then $a_k = a_{k - 1} + 5 a_{k - 2} + 3 a_{k - 3}$.

Now we need to solve this recurrence with initial conditions $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 6$.

[Characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) is $x^3 - x^2 - 5 x - 3$. It's roots are $3$ and $-1$ (with multiplicity $2$), so general solution is $a_k = A \cdot 3^k + B \cdot (-1)^k + C \cdot k \cdot (-1)^k$. Now we can substitute $k = 0, 1, 2$, get linear system for $A$, $B$, $C$ and solve it to get closed-form expression for $a_k$.

Comment: Why the initial conditions are  a0=1, a1=1, a2=6?

Comment: Because we have exactly one empty play list, exactly one playlist one minute long (the only one minute long song) and 6 playlists two minute long (either the one minute song twice, or one of 5 two-minute songs)

Comment: Ok , got it , thanks a lot!